# Can we fit extreme value distribution by build-in package?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I try to find a package in R to fit Gumbel distribution by Block Maxima Approach using maximal likelihood function (see [here](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Ehuang251/1018.html))
$$
G(x; \mu , \sigma)=\exp[-e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}].
$$

The block maxima approach is that we have $n$ iid random samples $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from $exp(1)$ (the limiting distribution of extreme value is Gumbel), and choose $m$ blocks with same size for $X_i$ and choose the maximal value of each block denoted by $Z_1, Z_2,\dots, Z_m$. Since $Z_i$ is the maximal value in $i-th$ block, we can approximate its distribution by Gumbel distribution.

In this website [https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~huang251/1018.html](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Ehuang251/1018.html), he used the package `fevd` to fit the generalized extreme value distribution with three parameters $(\mu, \sigma, \xi)$. Can we just fit two parameters? Is there any such package to fit Gumbel distribution?

Comment: Looking at [the documentation for the fevd() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/extRemes/versions/2.1-2/topics/fevd) it seems like you can just add the argument `type = "Gumbel"`. Is there a reason you haven't tried this, or that it won't work?

Comment: @awhug I am not familiar with this package. Where do I add this argument?

Comment: @awhug Do you mean `fevd(data, type="Gumbel")`?

Comment: Yes. E.g. with simulated data `x <- rexp(1000, 1.3); x_agg <- aggregate(x, list(gl(100, 10)), max); fit <- fevd(x_agg$x, type = "Gumbel")`

Comment: @awhug Thanks. But why the estimator's results for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are not $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @awhug I posted my results. Since $\exp(1)$ should be Gumbel with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, why the fitted value are not close to the true value?

Comment: Are you sure? $-log(X)$ where $X$ is exponential does give you that Gumbel distribution, but here you're fitting a model to the maxima across blocks of $X$, *not* every observation.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/d3a2f91b635d4c400c2e0e708545d928) is a gist for fitting a right-skewed Gumbel distribution in Python.

Comment: @awhug I add a solution about the limiting distribution of the maximal value of $\exp(1)$ is $G(x; 1, 0)$ in the update. Does not it mean $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simulation appears to be working as expected.

Here's a verification using `optim()` to directly maximise the log-likelihood function you've written yourself in the question (noting that the number of blocks, $m$, should actually be 1000 and not 100). The results are equivalent to what `fevd()` is estimating (within a margin of error).

```r
# Data generating process
n <- 100   # observations within each block
m <- 1000  # number of blocks
x <- rexp(n*m, 1)
x_agg <- aggregate(x, list(gl(m, n)), max)

# Optional: Rescale to force mu=0 and sigma=1
# x_agg$x <- x_agg$x - log(n)

# Log-likelihood function: Eq. 3.9 Coles (2001) pg. 55
ll_fn <- function(par, z, m){
  mu <- par[1]
  sigma <- par[2]
  -m * log(sigma) - sum((z - mu)/sigma) - sum(exp(-((z - mu)/sigma)))
}

# Fit using optim ----
# Note fnscale set to maximise ll_fn
# hessian = TRUE for Fisher Info if needed
fit1 <- optim(par = c(1, 1), 
              fn = ll_fn, z = x_agg$x, m = m,
              hessian = TRUE, control = list(fnscale = -1))
# $par
# [1] 4.661471 1.006802
#
# $value
# [1] -1588.832

# Fit using extRemes ----
fit2 <- fevd(x_agg$x, type = "Gumbel")
# Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  1588.832 
#
# Estimated parameters:
# location    scale 
# 4.661528 1.006741
```

In fact, without fitting a model at all you can verify that if the block maxima in this simulation are Gumbel distributed, this distribution can't be centred on $\mu = 0$.

Here's what the raw `x_agg$x` looks like just plotting the data

```r
# Simple histogram and density overlay
hist(x_agg$x, probability = TRUE, breaks = 38, xlab = "Block Maxima - rexp(1)")
lines(density(x_agg$x), lty = 2)
```

[image]

The proof you've reproduced above leading you to expect the parameter estimates to approach the standard Gumbel ($\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 1$) is actually based on rescaling the block maxima by the log number of observations within each block, i.e., $\text{max}\{X_1, \dots, X_m\} - \log(n)$. This rescale does indeed result in the standard Gumbel, which you can verify using the code above, but note that when working with the *raw* block maxima, the parameter estimates will differ.

A more comprehensive discussion on this is provided in Chapter 3 of Coles, S. (2001). An introduction to statistical modeling of extreme values. London: Springer.

Comment: I can't look at this again until tonight, but just quickly - I'd *guess* that $\mu$ here may be centred on the inverse CDF of the exponential at the quantile $1 - (1/n)$ where $n$ is the number of observations in each block (e.g. `qexp(1 - (1/100))` above). Can't prove this though. It looks like you've lifted your proof above directly from Example 3.1 in Coles (2001, pg. 52), but it's difficult to follow how it relates to the rest of the question.

Comment: I've just revised the answer and modified the code. You should be able to rescale the block maxima to get your standard Gumbel and check the MSE that way.

Comment: See point #13 [here](https://www.randomservices.org/random/special/ExtremeValue.html) for the same proof with cleaner notation.